# How to set SameSite cookie attribute to explicit None ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Chrome 76 will begin to support an explicit `SameSite: None` attribute

https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/

I found that the current implementation of ASP.NET Core treats `SameSiteMode.None` as a no-op and does not send any attribute. How can I add a custom attribute to a cookie and thereby add an explicit `SameSite: None` to the cookie text?

Appending the attribute to the cookie value does not work as HttpResponse.Cookies.Append url-encodes the cookie value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's now fixed in latest release of all versions of .NET Framework and .NET Core (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12125)

I have multiple projects running on .NET Core 2.2 and after upgrading to 2.2.207, I don't have the problem anymore.

Here a sample code present in `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup.cs` file

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
     options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

Comment: Can't see any reference to that this is fixed for .NET Framework - the link is for ASP .NET Core.

Comment: @FrodeNilsen Did you find whether or not it had been updated in .NET Framework? I have updated to 4.8 and am still having this problem

Comment: @MichaelHancock no fix as I am aware of, but see answer from Ygalbel below.

Comment: @MichaelHancock see my answer for .Net Framework: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60090446/198797

Comment: I wasted HOURS trying to figure out why this wasn't working. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 25):

Same issue occurs in ASP.NET as in ASP.NET Core.

Until Microsoft produce a fix, a hack that's working for me is to replace

```
myCookie.Path = "/";
myCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;     // has no effect
```

with

```
myCookie.Path = "/; SameSite=None";
```

This adds `SameSite=None` to the `set-cookie` header in the HTTP response.

Comment: Even after upgrading to .NET Framework 4.8 and having access to HttpCookie.SameSite property, the CookieHeaderValue class used by HttpResponseMessage in our code still did not have this property available. This hack may be ugly but is what finally worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I find that this clever hack works BUT only if you include the line "Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;"

Answer (score 8):

[Edit] 
If you are using all dlls and packages from nuget,
you have to ensure **Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers** is in version 2.2.8 of above.

After last KB from microsoft in 10 december 2019,
It should be fixed in .net framework and dotnetcore.

see:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/kbs-samesite

Comment: My ASP.Net Core v2.2 app absolutely would not output a SameSite=None cookie (short of setting a header manually as @dmi_ suggests) - any variety of attempts to do so resulted in an unspecified SameSite value. Installing Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers as you suggest resolved this.

Answer (score 3):

`response.Headers.Append("set-Cookie", $"{cookieName}={cookieValue}; path=/; SameSite=None; Secure");` seems to work as expected.

I tested this by enabling `same-site-by-default-cookies` and `cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure` in Chrome Dev 76

Comment: After december 2019, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have mentioned .Net Core fix, so I skip that part.

The .Net Framework fix is provided via a "Quality Rollup".

[Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4531182/kb4531182)'s the KB for .Net 4.8.

[Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4524421/kb4524421)'s the KB for .Net 4.7.2.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcookie.samesite?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)'s the relevant MSDN source.