ASP.NET Core doesn't create an authentication cookie when SameSite is set to none
I want to test a cross-domain authentication after some research it seems SameSite for authentication cookie should be set to none as below:
options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;

The problem is that when I set SameSite to none, the application can not create an authentication cookie but if set it to Lax or strict it works fine.
This is my code in program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(options =>
           {
               options.Cookie.Name = "authen";
               options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
               options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
               options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
               options.Cookie.Path = "/";
               options.Cookie.Domain = "localhost";
           });

Update
After some testing, it seems this happens only in Google Chrome and it works on Firefox fine.

Might wish to check version of your Chrome browser.  The documentation here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-8.0 specifically states that older versions do not support the SameSiteMode.None

Could also be related to version of .core you are using.  But the age of this fix makes me think it might not be what you need, but worth a shot:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56988877/samesite-cookie-attribute-ommited-by-asp-net-core

@Kevin my Chrome version is 128.0.6613.85 (Official Build) (64-bit) and I'm using .NET 8

Are you using HTTP or HTTPS? Samesite=None Cookies are blocked over HTTP. I blogged about how to troubleshoot cookie problems here https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/

could you try setting  options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always; or  options.Cookie.SecurePolicy =      env.IsDevelopment() ? CookieSecurePolicy.None : CookieSecurePolicy.Always;

Change this line code to
options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;

to
options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;

and it works.
